# Can I install and use LAMP with Wubi?

Tags: wubi, lamp

I would like to try the Ubuntu OS with the Windows installer and to set up an apache server for testing. Will this work? Can I call "sudo tasksel install lamp-server" to have LAMP installed on a Ubuntu Desktop install (via Wubi), or it only works with Ubuntu Server install?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since Wubi has the same features as a regular Ubuntu installation, only somewhat slower.  You can install Lamp on Ubuntu desktop.

But to do so

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

and then to install LAMP

```
sudo  tasksel
```